# make a combination (variations) of records on the basis of a dynamic column value (attributes) using sql

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

I have a table which contains **Attributes**

```
AttrId     Title  
1       |  Color  
2       |  Size  
3       |  Style
```

Another Table which contains **Variants**

```
Id      |   ProductId   |    AttrId    |    Value  
1       |   1           |    1         |    Red  
2       |   1           |    1         |    Green  
3       |   1           |    1         |    Blue  
4       |   1           |    2         |    Small  
5       |   1           |    2         |    Medium  
6       |   1           |    2         |    Large  
7       |   1           |    3         |    New  
8       |   1           |    3         |    Used
```

Now i want to make all possible combination related to **Attributes**

Output should be look like this:

```
Size    |     Color     |    Style  

Small   |     Red       |    New
Small   |     Red       |    Old
Small   |     Green     |    New 
Small   |     Green     |    Old
Small   |     Blue      |    New  
Small   |     Blue      |    Old
Medium  |     Red       |    New
Medium  |     Red       |    Old
Medium  |     Green     |    New 
Medium  |     Green     |    Old
Medium  |     Blue      |    New  
Medium  |     Blue      |    Old
Large   |     Red       |    New
Large   |     Red       |    Old
Large   |     Green     |    New 
Large   |     Green     |    Old
Large   |     Blue      |    New  
Large   |     Blue      |    Old
```

So, there's 18 possible Combinations **(Variations)** with **Attributes**

Attributes and Variants can be dynamic

How is this possible in SQL Server Database Query?

Answer (score 1):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/LBMZ1850)**

```
WITH Color as (
    SELECT V.[Value] as Color
    FROM Attributes A
    JOIN Variants V
      ON A.[AttrId]= V.[AttrId]
    WHERE A.[AttrId] = 1
), Size as (
    SELECT V.[Value] as Size
    FROM Attributes A
    JOIN Variants V
      ON A.[AttrId]= V.[AttrId]
    WHERE A.[AttrId] = 2
), Style as (
    SELECT V.[Value] as Style
    FROM Attributes A
    JOIN Variants V
      ON A.[AttrId]= V.[AttrId]
    WHERE A.[AttrId] = 3
)     
SELECT *
FROM Color
CROSS APPLY Size    
CROSS APPLY Style;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I mentioned above Attributes can be dynamic. if more attributes, what should be the query then.?

Comment: Im thinking, but not an easy task. Probably you have to use a Store Proc and handle a Loop

Comment: Can you please elaborate more clearly via stored procedure?

Comment: You can build my query using [dynamic query](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/) You create an string and then `SP_EXECUTE @theSql`

Answer (score 1):

Here is doing a dynamic sql. You loop from the Attributes table and create a cte and a cross join for each one.  Then execute the dynamic sql. You will get the same result.

**[SQL DEMO:](http://rextester.com/DPU97559)**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCombinations(@TableName varchar(20))  
 AS
 BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql varchar(4000);
    DECLARE @cte varchar(4000);
    DECLARE @select varchar(4000);

    DECLARE Cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [AttrId], [Title] FROM Attributes;

    OPEN Cur;

    SELECT @cte = 'WITH ';
    SELECT @select = 'SELECT * FROM ';

    DECLARE @AttrId VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE @Title VARCHAR(255);

    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @AttrId, @Title;        
    WHILE ( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )
        BEGIN                                    
            SELECT @cte = @cte + @Title + ' as (' + 
                        'SELECT V.[Value] as ' + @Title + ' ' +
                        'FROM Attributes A ' +
                        'JOIN Variants V ' +
                        'ON A.[AttrId]= V.[AttrId] ' +
                        'WHERE A.[AttrId] = ' + @AttrId + 
                        '), ';         

            SELECT @select = @select + @Title + ' CROSS APPLY ';

            FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @AttrId, @Title;            
        END

    SELECT @cte = LEFT(@cte, LEN(@cte) - 1);
    SELECT @select = LEFT(@select, LEN(@select) - 12);

    -- for debug --
    SELECT @sql= 'SELECT  ''' + @cte + @select + ''' as title';

    EXEC (@cte + @select);  

 END;
```